# A word for "a forceful part that temporarily becomes part of a whole without losing its unique identity"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am struggling to find the word that best resembles the above situation.
I have been looking through some synonyms and antonyms but cannot quite get the right word.

**Context**
I am talking about a human individual who temporarily becomes part of a team or organization and through his/her being, injects a powerful change to that whole without actually being assimilated by the whole and thus keeping his/her unique identity through which contribution to the resulting state remains distinguishable.

**Origin**
The question results from a conceptual exploration into the distinguishable added value of an ideation consultant/advisor, strengths-based teaming and the word *impetus*.

**First ideas**
I was looking at words like: *fuse*, *merge*, *mix*, *blend* but these are all related to chemicals and take the notion that the individual properties of the elements involved either dissolve or become highly diluted and thus hard to distinguish.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I had to correct 3 typos in your question. Hint: when the word processor underlines a word in red, it is asking you to check the  spelling.

Comment: Do you have an example or two of real-life mechanisms, reactions, or other systems where this actually occurs? That will help us hunt down appropriate words for you.

Comment: FWIW, "Fuse, Merge, Mix, Blend" can all be used for your example, too, but they all are the same concept of becoming part of the whole without retaining their individuality.  You might try looking up synonyms for "influence", "motivator" or "impression".

Comment: 'Catalyst' is probably not ideal either.

Comment: 'Dominant' would suit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *facilitator* ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facilitator))

> someone or something that facilitates something; especially : someone who helps to bring about an outcome (such as learning, productivity, or communication) by providing indirect or unobtrusive assistance, guidance, or supervision the workshop's facilitator kept discussion flowing smoothly

Comment: @ 0xFEE1DEAD - Thank you for your suggestion. I understand your take on it but feel a facilitator is indeed indirect or unobtrusive instead of actively contributing and changing force.

Answer (score 1):

I like "catalyst".

> a person or thing that precipitates an event.
>
> "the governor's speech acted as a catalyst for debate"
>
> In chemistry, a substance that causes a chemical reaction to occur but is not itself involved in the reaction.

UPDATE: Upon further discussion with the questioner, I have thought of a better answer, and would like to present it here, as a change of mind (it happens, occasionally):

Instead of catalyst, I now think **key** is a good choice for characterizing an individual person who temporarily engages with a group in a useful way that contributes to their success, without losing their unique identity. As in "Perry was the **key** individual in the group, to obtaining success in that venture."

https://iris.peabody.vanderbilt.edu/module/rti-leaders/cresource/q2/p05/

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/key-player

> The key players in a particular organization, event, or situation are the most important people or things involved in it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Interestingly enough I already had "catalyst" before as well but dismissed it as to me it also felt more of an instigating force not necessarily involved in the whole and as such identifiable as major contributing factor to the change.

Comment: I see you point. But I just thought of another one: the word "key" is often used metaphorically as meaning "temporarily becomes part of the whole, without using its unique identity". As in, Mr. X was a key (individual) for that group's overall success.  https://iris.peabody.vanderbilt.edu/module/rti-leaders/cresource/q2/p05/

Answer (score 1):

There is a word in the back of my mind somewhere, but the synapses aren't firing sufficiently to bring the word to the tip of my tongue.

Nevertheless, until that word emerges from the primordial goo that passes as a brain, what you describe is what happens in a [symbiotic relationship](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/symbiosis), in which two organisms exert a beneficial effect (though not always beneficial) on each other without ceasing to be what they were before.

A variation of the symbiotic relationship is called a commensalistic relationship, in which one plant such as an epiphyte (e.g., bromeliad) benefits by its relationship to another plant, but the host plant is unaffected. In other words, their is neither a positive nor negative effect on the host plant.

Now, the challenge is to come up with one word which describes the phenomenon you've described, and that is where I am stymied again. Two words or more? Yes. One word? No. Here's my stab at describing your phenomenon:

> The ideational consultant our group hired, Frank Baxter, provided us with the impetus to take our initially inchoate goal of increasing our market share, and in a truly symbiotic/commensalistic relationship with us, he helped our team to define, refine, and delimit our goal. As a result, we felt empowered to take some concrete steps in having a record-setting year.

See the website and video [here](https://tropical-ecology.wikispaces.com/Symbiotic+Relationships+of+the+Tropics), which define and illustrate the three types of symbiotic relationships: parasitism, mutualism, and commensalism.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input and good example. I researched your symbiotic relationships angle. Initially I would lean to mutualism. Yet I struggle with the omission of both the temporary state of the relationship and the forceful injection aka benefit of the one part over the whole. It made me cross-jump onto "synergy" yet that does not seem to be it either.